# cpack: how to associate program with file extension during install?

Tags: nsis, cpack

I'm creating a windows installer with CPack and NSIS. During the install process the user should be asked if he wants to associate my program with a file extension. At least if you do "open with..." on a file with the extension windows should be told that you can open it with my program. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your nsis installation folder on you system and have a look at makensis.nsi from the examples directory. It associates .nsi to makensisw.exe.
Good luck ;)

Comment: also check http://nsis.sourceforge.net/File_Association and http://nsis.sourceforge.net/FileAssoc

Comment: then I just have to tell cpack to use my .nsi file?

Answer (score 0):

To create file associations using NSIS I would recommend using NSIS plugins mentioned by Andrei T: [File Association](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/File_Association) and [FileAssoc](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/FileAssoc). To integrate them into CPack you need to include the script, call macro during install step, call other macro during uninstall step.
For example this is how I use "File Association" plugin:

```
# Including
set(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_PREINSTALL_COMMANDS
    "!include \\\"${path_to_plugins}\\\\fileassoc.nsh\\\"")

# Create association
set(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS
    "\\\${RegisterExtension} '$INSTDIR\\\\myprogram.exe' '.myext' 'my_program_key'")
# my_program_key can be any string that gives some hint what this file type is about. And should not contain strings

# Remove association
set(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_UNINSTALL_COMMANDS
    "\\\${UnRegisterExtension} '.myext' 'my_program_key'")
```

In this implementation it is not an optional step.

Please note the double escape. It is required because CPack creates intermediate file with those strings and if you escape only once there will be a syntax error.

Also note that all CMake paths should use back slashes. I convert them with:

```
get_filename_component(path_to_plugins"${path_to_plugins}" ABSOLUTE)
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${path_to_plugins}" path_to_plugins)
string(REPLACE "\\" "\\\\" path_to_plugins"${path_to_plugins}")
```